# About Dagger 2. Connection of @inject and @provide

Tags: dagger-2

If there is @inject, then it means there must be @provide?
inject field gets its value from @provide method of module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you use Module

```
@Module
public class SomeModule {
    @Provides
    Unscoped unscoped() {
        return new Unscoped();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Scoped scoped() {
        return Scoped();
    }
}
```

**BUT** classes with `@Inject` constructor get automatically appended to your scoped component even if no module is specified for it:

```
@Singleton
public class Scoped {
    @Inject
    public Scoped() {
    }
}

public class Unscoped {
    @Inject
    public Unscoped() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is @Inject annotation then it's dependency can be provided in two ways :

**By Using Provides annotation in module**

```
@Provides
    TasksPresenter provide TasksPresenter(TasksRepository tasksRepository, TasksContract.View tasksView) {
        return new TasksPresenter(tasksRepository,tasksView);
}
```

**By Using Constructor Injection**

```
 @Inject
    TasksPresenter(TasksRepository tasksRepository, TasksContract.View tasksView) {
        mTasksRepository = tasksRepository;
        mTasksView = tasksView;
    }
```

One thing to observe here is Constructor Injection solve two thing

- Instantiate object
- Provides the object by adding it to Object graph.